# Is an anonymous function as a parameter a function declaration or a function expression?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, function-expression, javascript-function-declaration

Assuming a **function declaration** is a statement where the function keyword is the first word of the statement, e.g.:

```
function() { console.log("foo") };
```

Assuming that a **function expression** is e.g. following:

for a named function

```
var func = function doSomething() { console.log("foo") };
```

for an anonymous function

```
var func = function() { console.log("foo") };
```

What is the case for the anonymous function, which is passed in as parameter in the following example:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 200); 
};
```

Is that a *function declaration* or is it a *function expression* since it is getting assigned to a parameter-variable of the setTimeout-method of [WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: They are not statement, therefore, they are expressions.

Comment: You can't write a statement within another statement; it can only be an expression.

Comment: # Response if you really what to know that you need to have a clear understanding of how the javascript runtime engine works. ## Detailed Video https://youtu.be/QyUFheng6J0

Comment: `var func = …;` is not a function expression, it's an variable declaration with an initialiser - a statement. Only the `function() {…}` part is an expression in there. And yes, it's the same in an argument position.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly a function expression

From MDN

### [Function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)

> The function keyword can be used to define a function inside an expression.

---

> Syntax
>
> ```
> let myFunction = function [name]([param1[, param2[, ..., paramN]]]) {
>    statements
> };
> ```

---

> A function expression is very similar to and has almost the same
>   syntax as a function declaration (see function statement for details).
>   The main difference between a function expression and a function
>   declaration is the function name, which can be omitted in function
>   expressions to create anonymous functions. A function expression can
>   be used as an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) which
>   runs as soon as it is defined. See also the chapter about functions
>   for more information.

---

---

### [Function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)

> Syntax
>
> ```
> function name([param[, param,[..., param]]]) {
>    [statements]
> }
> ```